# How to use google url shortner api by UrlFetchApp.fetch correctly?

Tags: google-apps-script

I spent a lot of time reading google manuals and other resources and didn't find out what I'm doing wrong when trying to get short url using this script:

```
function test_short_link() {
  var apiKey, post_url, options, result;
  post_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url";
  apiKey = 'xxx';//here is real apiKey
  post_url += '?key=' + apiKey;
  var options =
     { 'method':'post',
       'headers' : {'Content-Type' : 'application/json'},
       "resource": {"longUrl": "https://google.com/"},
       'muteHttpExceptions': true
     }
   result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(post_url, options);
   Logger.log(result);
}
```

I did various modifications but it returns:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Required",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "resource.longUrl"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Required"
 }
}
```

It drives me mad! 
Please help! What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to modify this code as it hard codes the longUrl and does no error checking. Some of the important parts are that the API options are sent in the payload of the UrlFetchApp options object and that you need to pass the current users OAuth token in the header.

```
function ShortenUrl(){
var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url"

var payload = {"longUrl":"www.google.com"};

var parameters = { method : 'post',
                    headers : {'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
                    payload:JSON.stringify(payload),
                    contentType:'application/json',                    
                    muteHttpExceptions:true};

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, parameters);
  Logger.log(response);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also an [advanced Google service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/url-shortener) to do it more simply.

You'll need to activate it from the script editor ressource menu (see illustrations below.)

Code is as simple as that :

```
function shortenUrl(longUrl) {
  var toShorten = UrlShortener.newUrl().setLongUrl(longUrl);
  var shortened = UrlShortener.Url.insert(toShorten);
  return shortened.id;
}
```

Just use it as in this test function below :

```
function test(){
  var shortUrl = shortenUrl("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script");
  Logger.log(shortUrl);
}
```

[image]

[image]